# Problems joining several tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I always look for the solution but today I surrender so please I need help.

I am using two 'inner join' because I need to get the sum of balances from two tables, but  the command 'inner join ' doubles the  valor when I use sum(column 1, column 2), while that when I use sum(Column 1) everything  is ok.

For example:
this query work very well, but I also have to query from other table called casilleros.

```
select datos_usuarios.id_cliente, 
       datos_usuarios.nombre , 
       sum(membresia.saldo) 
from  datos_usuarios  
inner join membresiaondatos_usuarios.id_cliente=membresia.id_socio        
where saldo>0
group by datos_usuarios.id_cliente, datos_usuarios.nombre
```

I had tried many thing for example

```
select datos_usuarios.id_cliente, 
       datos_usuarios.nombre, 
       sum(membresia.saldo+casilleros.saldo) 
from datos_usuarios 
inner join membresia on  datos_usuarios.id_cliente=membresia.id_socio 
inner join casilleros on datos_usuarios.id_cliente=casilleros.id_socio 
group by datos_usuarios.id_cliente, datos_usuarios.nombre
```

But the result is wrong.

I tried with 'union all' but honestly It is not that I need.Because I need only one result of balance  per client

Answer (score 0):

```
select t0.id_cliente, 
       t0.nombre, 
       cast(sum(t1.saldo) + sum(t2.saldo) as decimal (10,2)), 
       from  datos_usuarios t0
inner join membresia t1 on  t0.id_cliente=t1.id_socio 
inner join casilleros t2 on t0.id_cliente=t2.id_socio 
group by t0.id_cliente, t0.nombre
```

Comment: I'm working on a very similar report, and it worked fine for me. Sorry I couldn't be much of assistance

Answer (score 0):

UNION ALL is probably what you really want. But you want it as a derived table. Then do the sum in the outer query.

```
Select a.id_cliente, a.nombre, sum(a.saldo) 
From
(select datos_usuarios.id_cliente, datos_usuarios.nombre, membresia.saldo from 
 datos_usuarios 
 inner join membresia on  datos_usuarios.id_cliente=membresia.id_socio 
 inner join casilleros on datos_usuarios.id_cliente=casilleros.id_socio 
UNion all 
 select datos_usuarios.id_cliente, datos_usuarios.nombre, casilleros.saldo from 
 datos_usuarios 
 inner join casilleros on datos_usuarios.id_cliente=casilleros.id_socio 
) a
group by  a.id_cliente, a.nombre
```

Comment: I am sorry but a I can try with your code, I got La columna 'membresia.saldo' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get this query

```
;WITH mc AS (
    SELECT saldo, id_socio
      FROM membresia
    UNION 
    SELECT saldo, id_socio
      FROM casilleros
)
SELECT 
    datos_usuarios.id_cliente,
    datos_usuarios.nombre,
    sum(mc.saldo)
FROM datos_usuarios
JOIN mc ON mc.id_socio = datos_usuarios.id_cliente
GROUP BY datos_usuarios.id_cliente, datos_usuarios.nombre
```

We union two tables with the same structure in one pseudo table mc ([using CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)) and then join our new table with table datos_usuarios.